# Where can I find Azure storage cmdlets for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure

[David Aitken's blog post](http://www.davidaiken.com/2008/11/19/peeking-windows-azure-queues-using-windows-powershell/) and another post I cannot find anymore talk about PowerShell cmdlets within a CloudDrive example that let you manipulate Azure storage blobs and queues.  Where are these now?  He refers (presumably based on Azure SDK 1.0) to a samples.zip file, but my SDK just contains a [Windows Azure SDK Samples](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204652) link.  I cannot find CloudDrive there, although it is mentioned in [this archive](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples).  Unfortunately the associated downloads omit CloudDrive.  I feel this must be somewhere really obvious, but I am too stupid to find it.

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative, please look at Azure Management Cmdlets developed by my company Cerebrata @ http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets. It covers Windows Azure Storage, Hosted Service Management, Diagnostics and SQL Azure. It's a commercial product though. HTH

Comment: I am using this Cerebrata Storage Studio and it is doing just what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI: WASM version 2.2.2 have support for uploading blobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://www.cerebrata.com/. They have more comprehensive version of Azure Cmdlets. However, it is not free.

http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Current version of WASM works with Azure SDK 1.3 and you can download it [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/azurecmdlets/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3912). 
To install WASM with Azure SDK 1.4 you can use workaround in [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/enriquelima/archive/2011/03/11/the-tale-of-how-the-powershell-cmdlets-got-installed-with.aspx)

If you have access to Remote Desktop to any of the deployed instances to Azure, you can just use cmdlets that are installed there. This is actually much better option if you want to debug your PowerShell script works or confirm how they run in real Azure environment.

Comment: WASM Documentation page says "cmdlets that wrap the Windows Azure Management and Diagnostics APIs".  Do they also support Azure storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Azure PowerShell which is provided by Microsoft. There are many storage PowerShell cmdlet there.

The msdn page is here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx

Download Link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x409